# How to fix this syntax error with NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a syntax error with my script and i don't understand...
i check so much times please help

```
if(errors) {
          res.render('register',{
        errors:errors,
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        req.flash('error_msg','This adress mail is already in db');
        res.render('register', {
          errors:errors
        })
  } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email:email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        });
     User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You create an account, u can now log');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
})
```

The error in my VSCODE Problems : (but the 126th line its my last line of my page...)

```
[ts] '{' expected. [1005] (126,25)
```

And in my terminal

```
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corentin\Documents\newLoginapp\index.js:22:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Please help its a little error but im a beginner and i dont understand where is  the problem..

Comment: Your first render block has a trailing `,` at the end of the object.  `res.render('register',{errors:errors,});`

Comment: Did you close your else block?

Comment: so what i need to do ?

Comment: yes i end it correctly i think

Comment: You can use extensions like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer to avoid this kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the last } from your else statement

```
if (errors) {
  res.render('register', {
    errors: errors,
  });
} else {
  User.findOne({
    email: email
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'This adress mail is already in db');
      res.render('register', {
        errors: errors
      })
    } else {
      var newUser = new User({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
      });
      User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
      });

      req.flash('success_msg', 'You create an account, u can now log');

      res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
  })
}  //<-- This one
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input... the error has change i past ur response :/

Comment: The code throws no syntax errors on js fiddle so there must be another piece of your code thats breaking or you didn't copy it correctly

Comment: i put '}})' where u tell me where to put the '{' and its work !! ty man

Answer (score 0):

This time there is no error in vscode but when i click the submit button with a duplicate email nothing appear and at the second click there is the form errors message...
I think its because my else User.findOne end at the end of the redirect user/login... but when in pu the '}' of the else a the end of the req.flash('error_msg') there is 9+ errors so i rly dont undersand

```
    router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

  req.checkBody('username', 'Veuillez renseigner un identifiant').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Veuillez renseigner une adresse email valide').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Veuillez renseigner un mot de passe').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas').equals(req.body.password);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render('register', {errors:errors});
  } else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.render('register', {errors:errors})
        req.flash('error_msg','Adresse email non dispo')
  } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email:email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
     User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    })

    req.flash('success_msg', 'Vous venez de créer un compte, vous pouvez désormais vous connecter');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
})
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing '}' at the end

Updated Code:

```
if (errors) {
    res.render('register', {
        errors: errors,
    });
} else {
    User.findOne({
        email: email
    }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'This adress mail is already in db');
            res.render('register', {
                errors: errors
            })
        } else {
            var newUser = new User({
                email: email,
                username: username,
                password: password
            });
            User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(user);
            });

            req.flash('success_msg', 'You create an account, u can now log');

            res.redirect('/users/login');
        }
    })
}
```